# How To Remove Old Widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

Teaching myself python GUI building.  Have a simple die roller program, which let's you pick the number and sides of dice.  It uses a `for` loop to generate a series of widgets that show the individual rolls and the total of every roll.

If I increase the number of dice, I get more widgets.

If I decrease the number of dice, I get fewer widgets.

My problem is that while more dice overwrites the old widgets, fewer entries don't kill the older ones.

Where should I be putting something like `widget.grid_remove()` or how do I go about redrawing everything each time someone presses the button?

```py
# Get the numbers off the spinboxen:
def rollDice():

  size=int(spin_die.get())
  dice=int(spin_number.get())
  total=0
  for i in range(0, dice): 
    roll=random.randint(1, size)
    total+=roll
    rollNumber=i+1
    lbl_roll = tk.Label(app, text="Roll " + str(rollNumber) + ": " + str(roll), font=("Source Code Pro Med    ium", 12))
    roll_grid = i+3
    lbl_roll.grid(column=0, row=roll_grid)

  lbl_total = tk.Label(app, text="Total: " + str(total), font=("Source Code Pro Medium", 12))
  lbl_total.grid(column=0, row=roll_grid+1)

# Create window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Die Roller")
app = tk.Frame(window)
app.grid()

# create text labels for spinboxen
lbl_die = tk.Label(app, text="Size of Die: ", font=("Source Code Pro Medium", 12))
lbl_die.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl_number = tk.Label(app, text="Number to roll: ", font=("Source Code Pro Medium", 12))
lbl_number.grid(column=0, row=1)

# Adjacent to each label, create a 1-100 spinbox
defaultDie = tk.StringVar()
defaultDie.set(6)
spin_die = tk.Spinbox(app, from_=1, to=100, width=4, textvariable=defaultDie)
spin_die.grid(column=1, row=0)

defaultNumber = tk.StringVar()
defaultNumber.set(2)
spin_number = tk.Spinbox(app, from_=1, to=100, width=4, textvariable=defaultNumber)
spin_number.grid(column=1, row=1)

# Create a button to start the action!
btn_number = tk.Button(app, text="Roll Dice", command=rollDice)
btn_number.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: keep all generated widgets on global list so you will have access to them when you want to remove them. And remove them in `rollDice` always before you create new onces.

Comment: you could use the ```.forget_all``` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep all generated widgets on global list so you will have access to them when you will remove them before you create new onces.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# Get the numbers off the spinboxen:
def rollDice():
  global all_labels # inform function to use external/global variable instead of local one when you do `= []`

  # destroy old widgets
  for item in all_labels:
        item.destroy()

  # create new empty list for new widgets    
  all_labels = [] 

  size = int(spin_die.get())
  dice = int(spin_number.get())
  total = 0
  for i in range(0, dice): 
    roll = random.randint(1, size)
    total += roll
    rollNumber = i+1
    lbl_roll = tk.Label(app, text="Roll " + str(rollNumber) + ": " + str(roll), font=("Source Code Pro Med    ium", 12))
    roll_grid = i+3
    lbl_roll.grid(column=0, row=roll_grid)
    all_labels.append(lbl_roll) # append

  lbl_total = tk.Label(app, text="Total: " + str(total), font=("Source Code Pro Medium", 12))
  lbl_total.grid(column=0, row=roll_grid+1)
  all_labels.append(lbl_total) # append

# --- main ---

# empty list at start
all_labels = []

# Create window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Die Roller")
app = tk.Frame(window)
app.grid()

# create text labels for spinboxen
lbl_die = tk.Label(app, text="Size of Die: ", font=("Source Code Pro Medium", 12))
lbl_die.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl_number = tk.Label(app, text="Number to roll: ", font=("Source Code Pro Medium", 12))
lbl_number.grid(column=0, row=1)

# Adjacent to each label, create a 1-100 spinbox
defaultDie = tk.StringVar()
defaultDie.set(6)
spin_die = tk.Spinbox(app, from_=1, to=100, width=4, textvariable=defaultDie)
spin_die.grid(column=1, row=0)

defaultNumber = tk.StringVar()
defaultNumber.set(2)
spin_number = tk.Spinbox(app, from_=1, to=100, width=4, textvariable=defaultNumber)
spin_number.grid(column=1, row=1)

# Create a button to start the action!
btn_number = tk.Button(app, text="Roll Dice", command=rollDice)
btn_number.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

`grid_remove()` removes only from grid but not from memory so you could show them again but I don't want to use them again so I use `destroy()` to remove them from memory and automatically they are removed from grid.